# Proving T-tetrominoes fit in a chessboard

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, tiling, chessboard, polyomino

I'm fairly new to discrete math, and I wasn't sure how to prove the following.

> Prove that if $n\geq 2$, then every $2^n \times 2^n$ chessboard can be tiled with non overlapping T-tiles.

If I draw it out, I can clearly see the answer, however I'm not sure how to prove it with induction.

Comment: There is no need for induction. For $n \ge 2$, you can tile $2^n \times 2^n$ chessboard by $4\times 4$ squares. Since can also tile a $4 \times 4$ square by $4$ T-tetrominos, you are done.

Comment: achille hui's argument works for a $4m\times 4n$ rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can divide $2^{n+1}\times 2^{n+1}$ in to four $2^{n}\times 2^{n}$ tables and each can be tiled by induction hypothetis, so you are done.

Clearly base case of induction table $4\times 4$ should not be a problem to see.